# Which distro for Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: operating-systems, pi-zero-w

Which distro is recommended for the new Raspberry Pi Zero W?

I want to code a few small projects which will not have

- graphics
- sound
- any added software other than my own programs

but will have

- WiFi communication
- USB access to sensors and control of devices
- UART  access to sensors and control of devices
- MySql and Sqlite
- good remote debugging capabilities

I am not concerned about the size of distro. A bonus would be if I can use the same distor on Orange Pi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need the graphical capabilities of the full Raspbian distro, I would recommend Raspbian Lite. Raspbian, has the largest user base and hence the most projects and tutorials available. The large user base and community support can make developing and troubleshooting your projects a lot easier. Both are available for [download](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) from the Pi foundation website.

I am not sure if Raspbian works on the Orange Pi (the site appears to be down at the moment).